# How to differentiate text and ImageUrl stored on Firebase?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I store text and ImageUrl in an array on firebase. My code is then supposed to randomly get one of the data (text and imageUrl). It is actually working with text as datas. But I need also to add image url (image stored on Uploadcare). The code need to read the data and if it is an image url (https://....) it has to show the image. 
I need to write a "if" condition but my question is more on how to manage it in html part. Depending on the result (imageurl or text) is has to use

or .

```
private getRandom() {
    let rand1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.cat1.words.length);


    let wordCat1 = this.cat1.words[rand1];

    var re = /https/gi; 
    if (wordCat1.search(re) == -1 ) { 
      console.log("Data 1 does not contain Image URL" ); 
    } else { 
      console.log("Data 1 contains ImageUrl" ); 
    } 

    return [wordCat1];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I believe you can achieve this by taking a bool variable and using this in your HTML file with the usage of `*ngIf` of Angular.

**XYZ.ts file =>**

```
isImageURL: boolean

private getRandom() {
    let rand1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.cat1.words.length);


    let wordCat1 = this.cat1.words[rand1];

    var re = /https/gi; 
    if (wordCat1.search(re) == -1 ) { 
      console.log("Data 1 does not contain Image URL" ); 
      isImageURL = false;
    } else { 
      console.log("Data 1 contains ImageUrl" ); 
      isImageURL = true;
    } 

    return [wordCat1];
}
```

Now, you have the bool value, you can use it in your HTML and populate whatever data you wanna populate

**XYZ.html =>**

```
<!-- This div checks if the URL is true or false and populates data for true value only -->
<div *ngIf='isImageURL'>
   <!-- Your content -->
<div>

<!-- This div checks if the URL is true or false and populates data for false value only -->
<div *ngIf='!isImageURL'>
   <!-- Your content -->
<div>
```

I am sure this is what you wanted. Let me know if you want anything else in the comment. Thanks :)